# How to fix the "blocked by CORS policy" error when making a API call to Tomcat server

Tags: cors, axios, tomcat8

I had the following error when I try to make a API call to a Tomcat 8 server using axios.

> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<your-web-app>/WEB-INF/web.xml` file of the web application where you intend to enable CORS and add a CORS Filter declaration and mapping.

   ```
     <filter>
     　　<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
     　　<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     　　<init-param>
     　　　　<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
     　　　　<param-value>*</param-value>
     　　</init-param>
     </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
     　　<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
     　　<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
   ```

   *Important: change `<param-value>*</param-value>` to only allow your website instead of `*` for security reason.

You might need to add other `<init-param>`. For example, you need to add `cors.allowed.headers` in order to accept your customized header such as `token`.
 Please read the [tomcat document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) for more info about Initialisation parameters.

2. Make the API call.

   ```
   axios
   .post('http://path/to/api'
   , {xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
   })
   .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
   });
   ```

It took me hours to figure out that I had to have the `{xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}` to make it work.

Hope it helps you.